# List of differing values appended into python list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, random, append

I have

```
import random
gamma = 1/7
rand1 = random.uniform(1.5, 2.5)
beta = rand1 * gamma
#print(beta)

empty = []
for i in range(100):
    empty.append(beta)
```

which gives the list `empty` as the same value of `beta` 100 times. However, what I wish to have is the list `empty` consisting of 100 different values of beta. How can this be achieved?

Comment: `empty = [gamma * random.uniform(1.5, 2.5) for _ in range(100)]`?

Comment: @tdelaney, apologies, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update beta value, or not referring anymore to beta:

```
empty = []
for i in range(100):
    empty.append(random.uniform(1.5, 2.5)*gamma)
```

Comment: Interesting, so is doing it all in one go the only way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

the multiplication of a constant on a list get the effect of expanding the list by itself a number of times equal to the constant

```
>>> [1,2]*10
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
>>>
```

what you want is something like this `empty = [gamma * random.uniform(1.5, 2.5) for _ in range(100)]` like Dani commented or what Dams show in his/her answers